# TestCafe fails to validate emoji icon

Tags: automation, automated-tests, emoji, e2e-testing, testcafe

TestCafe Automation Tool: I am composing a message with Emojis ICON. Got success with composing and sending. But getting assertion error if I tried to validate the sent message. Is there any way to handle the Emojis using TestCafe.

1) To compose:

```
testController.typeText(ComposerTextInput, textEmojis))
```

2) To validate sent message:

```
testController.expect(Selector('div')
    .with({ boundTestRun: testController })
    .withText(textEmojis).exists).ok())
```

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient to determine what causes this assertion error. Could you please describe the issue in greater detail? What kind of assertion error did you get? If it's possible, please provide us with a link to your application or a simple example so that we can reproduce this behavior on our side.

Comment: Also, it is not clear why you use the [boundTestRun](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#optionsboundtestrun) option here. It should be used only for [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions). Please check [this](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#calling-client-functions-from-nodejs-callbacks) topic in the TestCafe documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I succeeded to validate the emojis using attribute value of the emojis.

Comment: Am using 'boundTestRun' option here  because we are replacing the Aysnc / Await wit promises.